# Transform Javascript subArrays into one Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
array = ['bla', ['ble', 'bli'], 'blo', ['blu']]
```

I want it to be

```
array = ['bla', 'ble', 'bli', 'blo', 'blu']
```

Is there a simple function that can give me this particular result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Please look at Dave's answer or p.s.w.g's answers instead - they're superior. This code is horrible and should *not* be used (I can't delete an accepted answer).

You could do something like this:

```
var arr = ['bla', ['ble', 'bli'], 'blo', ['blu']];
var newArr = arr.toString().split(',');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QpTCe/)

Explanation:

It's pretty simple. `toString()` on an array containing arrays creates a string with all the elements in the top level, so that `[['abc']].toString()` results in 'abc' regardless of how "deep" in the array it is. After that, you just split the string you get into an array using `String.prototype.split` and you've accomplished your goal

Comment: Problem with splitting is if the content is a different type, you loose that type. AKA numbers would end up as strings.

Comment: and if the string has a comma in it, it won't work

Comment: Those are both very good points. @dave Your answer does seem superior.

Answer (score 34):

Updated for 2020:

You can now use [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) in all modern browsers.

> `var newArray = arr.flat([depth])`

```js
let result = ['bla', ['ble', 'bli'], 'blo', ['blu']].flat()
console.log(result);
result = ['bla', ['ble', ['bli', ['bom']]], 'blo', ['blu']].flat()
console.log(result);
result = ['bla', ['ble', ['bli', ['bom']]], 'blo', ['blu']].flat(2)
console.log(result);
result = ['bla', ['ble', ['bli', ['bom']]], 'blo', ['blu']].flat(Infinity)
console.log(result);
```

You can use `concat` to do this:

```
array = [].concat.apply([], array)
```

If you need to do it recursively (nested nested arrays), I would probably do it like this:

```
function flatten(arr, result) {
    if (typeof result === "undefined") {
        result = [];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
            flatten(arr[i], result);
        } else {
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 But this only works for arrays nested one level deep. e.g. `['bla', ['ble', ['bli']], 'blo', ['blu']]` yields `['bla', 'ble', ['bli'], 'blo', 'blu']`

Answer (score 11):

There is a new array prototype function called ***flat***. Currently, Microsoft browsers and Samsung Internet do not support this function. The syntax is simple:

```
array.flat([depth])
```

*depth* is an optional variable that specifies how many layers to flatten. The default is 1. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

The other answers that have been provided are good, but here's my implementation of a recursive method that will flatten arrays arbitrarily nested to any depth:

```js
var flatten = function(arr) {
    var out = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out.push.apply(out, Array.isArray(arr[i]) ? flatten(arr[i]) : [ arr[i] ]);
    }

    return out;
};
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8w3D/)

Note this relies on [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), which may not be available in older browsers. You can replace that with another array test if this is a problem (e.g. `arr[i].constructor == Array`)